# Activity starts multiple times when started from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a fragment which starts a new activity when a button is clicked.The activity is opened in Landscape mode. Right now, the activity is started multiple times. If I start the activity from another activity the behavior is fine and works fine. The multiple activity rendering happens only when started from a Fragment

Any idea how I can stop this behavior?

Here is the code:-

```
void teaserVideo_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            mIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
            mIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            mIntent.SetClass(this.Activity, typeof(VideoActivity));
            Activity.StartActivity(mIntent);

        }
```

Comment: Where's the code that launches this activity? (inside your fragment I mean). There is a bug somewhere in that code, otherwise it wouldn't start the activity multiple times.

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: @kha have added some code. Please have a look

Comment: @SagarZala have added some code. Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the method name, "touch" implies it's being called multiple times when the finger touches the video.

You can either set it up to only recognize a true "click", or simply catch the first event with a flag like this:

```
boolean intentLaunched = false;    

void teaserVideo_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!intentLaunched){
            intentLaunched = true;

            Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            mIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
            mIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            mIntent.SetClass(this.Activity, typeof(VideoActivity));
            Activity.StartActivity(mIntent);
        }

    }
```

Be sure to reset "intentLaunched" back to false in onResume() or something

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you are calling from Activity or Fragment the Activity have to start Once.
The problem is in code:

```
mIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
```

here the `ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront` will call the already created activity from the android stack to front.

```
mIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
```

here `ActivityFlags.NewTask` again a new activity will start in your android stack.
hence you will be ending up in calling multiple instances of Activity.
Just change your code to below:

```
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront); 
        mIntent.SetClass(this.Activity, typeof(VideoActivity));
        Activity.StartActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: I have tried this approach initially and it gives me the same result

Comment: @hello world: use ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront alone and check.